# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep on Mac for command make

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

When I run command "make", fellow error occurs:

**MacBook-Pro~/Downloads/mp-boost$make
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/libwep: code signing blocked mmap() of '/usr/local/lib/libwep'
    /usr/local/lib/libwep: code signing blocked mmap() of '/usr/local/lib/libwep'
make: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
make: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch**

How I can fix this error?

Comment: have you tried following the instructions at the end of the message?

Comment: Yes,I have tried, but not work.

Comment: You have to give us a better clue than just "not work". What didn't work when you did `xcode-select`?